# \bigg is not working for left parenthesis

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath, delimiters

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xfrac, array, tabu, multirow, graphicx, setspace, dcolumn, tikz}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
%the argument for d specifies the maximum number of decimal places
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
x^2&=\sum_{x=1}^{30} \bigg((f_{obs}-f_{exp}\bigg)^2/f_{exp}\\
x^2&=\underline{10.55}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

I can't seem to find the mistake, what am I missing?

Comment: How about `\biggl(` and `\biggr)`?

Comment: do you really mean to have two left parentheses together after the first `\bigg`?  (the first one is properly "biggified", but the second one is ordinary text size, if that's what you're looking at.)  you should probably also set the subscripts as `_{\text{obs}}`, etc., so they won't be in the special italic used for variables that are multiplied together.

Comment: \biggl and \biggr worked perfect, also many thanks for the _{\text{ons}} suggestion, it looks much cleaner now

Comment: It is unclear to me what the "mistake" is that you refer to.  `\bigg` produces large parentheses for me.  Pluton's comment shows the more usual coding, that gives correct spacing. Barbara Beeton's comment provides good improvements to the general code.  I think we show close this as "not clear what you are asking"